# set jquery parameter in html javascript

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown

I am using js file to calculate remained time for elements that are coming from database .each element has an expire time .by calculation i want to show remained time to end-user. in this way i encountered a problem .all countdown timer show the same time please help me to solve it .
js file

```
    function CountDown() {

        this.start_time = "02:00:00:23";
        this.target_id = ".timer";
        this.name = "timer";
    }

CountDown.prototype.init=function(){
    this.reset();
    setInterval(this.name+'.tick()',1000);
}
CountDown.prototype.reset=function(){
    time = this.start_time.split(":");
    this.days = parseInt(time[0]);
    this.hours = parseInt(time[1]);
    this.minutes=parseInt(time[2]);
    this.seconds = parseInt(time[3]);
    this.update_target();
}

CountDown.prototype.tick=function(){
    if (this.seconds > 0 || this.minutes > 0 || this.hours > 0 ||this.days>0) {

        if (this.hours == 0 && this.minutes == 0 && this.seconds == 0) {
            this.days = this.days - 1;
            this.hours = 23;
            this.minutes = 59;
            this.seconds = 59;
        }
        if (this.minutes == 0 && this.seconds==0) {
            this.hours = this.hours - 1;
            this.minutes = 59;
            this.seconds = 59;
        }
        else if (this.seconds == 0) {
            this.minutes = this.minutes - 1;
            this.seconds = 59;
        }
        else {
            this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
        }

    }
    this.update_target();
}

CountDown.prototype.update_target = function () {
    seconds = this.seconds;
    minutes = this.minutes;
    hours = this.hours;
    days = this.days;
    if (seconds<10) 
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0"+ minutes;
    if (hours < 10)
        hours = "0" + hours;
    if (days < 10)
        days = "0" + days;
    $(this.target_id).val(days+":"+hours+":"+minutes + ":" + seconds)
   // $(this.target_id).val(this.minutes+":"+seconds) 


}
```

So in html i use below code for each item and pass the remained time to the jquery parameter to show

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
                                    {
                                            <li class="item-player">
                                            <a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="text-decoration:none">
                                                <img src="~/img/players/@item.img" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="info-player" dir="rtl" style="text-align:right;resize:horizontal">
                                                    <h5 style="background-color:white;text-align:justify;max-width:60%;height:25px;resize:horizontal;overflow:auto" dir="rtl"><a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="color:black;height:30px;text-decoration:none;text-align:right;font-size:95%">@item.name </a></h5><br/>


 <input type="text" class="timer" style="height:30px;color:black"/>
                                                    <script>
                                                        timer[@i] = new CountDown();
                                                        timer[@i].start_time = "@item.name";
                                                        timer[@i].init();
                                                    </script>
                                                    <h5 style="text-decoration:none;text-align:justify;font-size:90%;max-width:60%"><a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="text-decoration:none;text-align:right;font-size:95%"><span>@item.price</span></a></h5>
                                                    <div class="overlay-player">
                                                        <a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="text-decoration:none;text-align:right;font-size:90%">
                                                            <h6 style="color:white;font-size:90%" dir="rtl">  تعداد ثبت نام کننده گان :
                                                                @foreach (var item1 in ViewData["regs"] as Dictionary<int, int>)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (item1.Key == item.ID)
                                                                    {

                                                                        <label>@item1.Value</label>
                                                                        a = item1.Value * Convert.ToInt32(item.price);

                                                                    }

                                                                }
                                                            </h6></a>
                                                        <a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="text-decoration:none;text-align:right;font-size:90%">
                                                            <h6 style="color:white;" dir="rtl"> تعداد بازی :
                                                                @foreach (var item1 in Model.Item2)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (item1.Key == item.ID)
                                                                    {
                                                                        <label>@item1.Value</label>

                                                                    }
                                                                } 
                                                            </h6>
                                                            </a>
                                                        <a href="~/Form/Firstaction?ID=@item.ID" style="text-decoration:none;text-align:right;font-size:90%">
                                                            <h6 style="color:white;font-size:90%" dir="rtl"> مبلغ کل - ریال : @a </h6>

                                                            @{a = 0;
                                                                PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
                                                                <h6 style="color:white;text-align:right;font-size:90%">
                                                                    مهلت ثبت نام :
                                                              @p.GetHour(item.dt):@p.GetMinute(item.dt):@p.GetSecond(item.dt)&nbsp;&nbsp;  @p.GetYear(item.dt)/@p.GetMonth(item.dt)/@p.GetDayOfMonth(item.dt)
                                                                </h6>
                                                            }
                                                            </a>
                                                     </div>
                                                </div>

                                        </li>
                                                                    i = i + 1;
                                                                }
```

the problem is for code below

```
<input type="text" class="timer" style="height:30px;color:black"/>
                                                        <script>
                                                            timer[@i] = new CountDown();
                                                            timer[@i].start_time = "@item.name";
                                                            timer[@i].init();
                                                        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a class name as your element selector. Use an ID instead

```
function CountDown(element_id) {
    this.start_time = "02:00:00:23";
    this.target_id = "#" + element_id;
    this.name = "timer";
}
```

And I would create that object like this:

```
<input type="text" id="@item.ID" class="timer" style="height:30px;color:black"/>
<script>
    timer[@i] = new CountDown('@item.ID');
    timer[@i].start_time = "@item.name";
    timer[@i].init();
</script>
```

And then use that element instead of the class selector, like this:

```
$(this.target_id).val(days+":"+hours+":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

---

Replace your `.ini()` with something like this:

```
CountDown.prototype.init=function(){
    this.reset();
    var timer = this;
    setInterval(function () { timer.tick() },1000);
}
```

There is no `timer.tick()`,  this line `setInterval(this.name+'.tick()',1000);` in your init prototype is incorrect.

Comment: By doing this edition I encounter below error in jquery file                                                                Uncaught TypeError: timer.tick is not a function

Comment: THANXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx

Comment: You're welcome, hope it helped.. And if you find this answer helpful, you might want to mark it as answer so we can also help other people like us.